# Node.js app running in docker container is not reachable

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I want to run a node.js app in a docker container using docker-compose. The app is TiddlyWiki, there are other containers and the whole thing runs in a vagrant VM and is set up with ansible, but I don't think any of that matters for this problem.

This is my docker-compose config:

```
        wiki:
          image: node:12-alpine
          container_name: nodejs
          restart: always
          working_dir: /home/node/app
          environment:
            NODE_ENV: production
          volumes:
            - "/srv/docker_wiki/:/home/node/app"
          ports:
            - "8080:8080"
          command: "node node_modules/tiddlywiki/tiddlywiki.js mywiki --listen debug-level=debug"
```

The app seems to start up and run without issues:

```
vagrant@vserver:~$ sudo docker logs nodejs
Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080
(press ctrl-C to exit)
syncer-server-filesystem: Dispatching 'save' task: $:/StoryList
```

But I cannot reach it:

```
vagrant@vserver:~$ curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
vagrant@vserver:~$ curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

It seems random which of the two different error messages comes up.

An interesting detail: If I use the default node image which comes itself with curl, then I can in fact reach the app from within the container itself after running `docker exec -it nodejs /bin/bash`

I have also tried to use a different port on the host, with the same result.

Any idea what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An interesting detail: If I use the default node image which comes
>   itself with curl, then I can in fact reach the app from within the
>   container itself after running docker exec -it nodejs /bin/bash

If you are able to access inside the container, it means the application bind with `127.0.0.1` the localhost of the container.

```
Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080
(press ctrl-C to exit)
```

All need to bind it with `0.0.0.0`.

so change the command to

```
command: "node node_modules/tiddlywiki/tiddlywiki.js mywiki --host 0.0.0.0 --listen debug-level=debug"
```

or

```
command: "node node_modules/tiddlywiki/tiddlywiki.js mywiki --listen debug-level=debug host=0.0.0.0"
```

You explore further [ListenCommand](http://tiddlywiki.com/static/ListenCommand.html) here.

Comment: Thanks, binding to 0.0.0.0 was the key. However it worked only when I used your second version and removed the `--host 0.0.0.0` part, otherwise the app would fail to start with the error message "Error: Unknown command: host" in the logs.

Comment: Yes, that is why I posted both commands. the first one is nodejs or http-server based flag, but the app using it own listen command that is explained here http://%20https//tiddlywiki.com/static/ListenCommand.html.